# Referencing a "referenced cell" within a formula to Offset and get data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Apologies if I use incorrect terminology ...    ok, here's the gist of it.

I work in a data center and we keep a spreadsheet of the inventory of all the equipment out on the data center floor.  I also created a spreadsheet to use on my walkthroughs and when I want to verify the inventory.  Our inventory spreadsheet is very detailed but for my spreadsheet, I only need certain columns (but it's always the same columns that I'm wanting).

Example of main inventory spreadsheet
[image: INVENTORY SPREADSHEET]

What I want in my spreadsheet
[image: MY SPREADSHEET]

So here's what I'm trying to accomplish.  Instead of copying and pasting and deleting columns that I don't need,  I want to reference the Asset Tag (which is always in the A column) in my inventory list (in a different workbook) and Offset to the other corresponding column titles and copy that data over to my list.

Example:  A2 in my list would be ='[MDC_Inventory.xlsx] Tagging Data'!$A$2  which would result in 13579.  So in my B2 I need a formula that references the cell location from my A2 ( which is pointing to A2 in our inventory) and then offsets (in the inventory list) however many columns in order to retrieve the data under the title Serial Number and inserts it in my B2.

Then I would repeat the same steps for the rest of the columns in my list.

Any Ideas?

Comment: `OFFSET(...)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but why do you need a formula? The columns in the inventory sheet stays the same right? Why not just have (in your columns):

```
 ='[MDC_Inventory.xlsx] Tagging Data'!A2     ='[MDC_Inventory.xlsx] Tagging Data'!C2         ='[MDC_Inventory.xlsx] Tagging Data'!D2    ...
```

You can then copy that down (referencing every row), and use a filter to select only the rows / items you want. You can even make a "Select" column in column A, mark the relevant ones with an "X" and then filter for those.

**If instead you want or need to use a lookup function:**

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, '[MDC_Inventory.xlsx] Tagging Data'!DATA,3,FALSE)
```

where
DATA is the whole data range define by a named range (or you could just use e.g. $A$2:$Z$100000), and "3" is the offset to third column (Serial number in this case)

Note: This method could be a bit slow if you have lots and lots of data. It also requires column A to be unique.

Comment: I didn't want to just tag the individual cells because I would be doing that eight to fifteen times just for one row, depending on how many columns of data I decide to use.  But with that vlookup, I only have to tag one cell and the "offset" does the rest for me.  As I copied the formula down and discovered the N/A error, I added the N/A fix with it and ended up with =IFNA(VLOOKUP($A2,'MDC_Inventory01.19.2021.xlsx'!Inventory_Data,3,FALSE),"")  Thanks for your help!